# How to Hide Menu Item Based on User's Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to this site and i have researched online so  many times in the past and could not get this issue resolved. I basically want to hide a menu item if user is not authorized and  i am using a windows authentication method.  My problem with this code is that the Menu Item called "Admin" is hidden even though i am in the Admin role.  I basically have a file called Admin.aspx under a folder called Admin.  In the Admin folder, i have a web config and this is how i configured it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="~/Admin/Authors.aspx"></location>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />

            <allow users="Perf_Mon" />
            <allow roles="Perf_Mon" />

        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />

                <add accessType="Allow" roles="Admin" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am also using the code behind in the Master page file since i have all my menu in there and the code is here:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Not Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") Then
            Dim menuItems As MenuItemCollection = NavigationMenu.Items
            Dim adminItem As New MenuItem()
            For Each menuItem As MenuItem In menuItems
                If menuItem.Text = "Admin" Then
                    adminItem = menuItem
                End If
            Next
            menuItems.Remove(adminItem)
        End If
    End Sub
```

So i am wondering why the Admin Menu is hidden from me even though i am in the Admin role.  I am not sure what i am doing wrong.  thanks
Here is the ASP file for the Master Page

```
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    Home Page
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
                        ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold">
                            <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />
                        </span>! [
                        <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out"
                            LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                        ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Authors.aspx" Text="Admin" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Users/MyTest1.aspx" Text="Summary" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Users/MyTest2.aspx" Text="Details" />

                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

it is referencing the Master page in this line how can we change it to reference the site map?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" CodeFile="Authors.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Authors1" %>
```

Comment: I'm infornt of my machine, can you post the asp too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First place this code in your web.config within your `<system.web>` tags

```
  <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" siteMapFile="/NavMenu.sitemap" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
```

now add a new sitemap item to your project and name it NavMenu.sitemap, then populate with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="#" title="Menu"  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/Author.aspx" title="Admin" roles="Admin"/>
        <siteMapNode url="http://www.google.co.uk" title="Google" roles="*"/>
        <siteMapNode url="http://www.hotmail.co.uk" title="Hotmail" roles="*"/>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

now in your site.master (or whereever you have placed your Menu) replace you menu with these two lines:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="NavMenuDS"></asp:Menu>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="NavMenuDS" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider"/>
```

Now I'll explain (or try) what each of these are:
The first block of code is declaring the sitemap provider without this you can't read the sitemap file, NavMenuDS then uses this provider information to populate the NavigationMenu.

in the sitemap file you'll notice at the end of the admin line the `role="Admin"` is specified, well that's your line, the rest of the items need to have `role="*"`.

Any Q's fier them over....

Comment: David, i am using windows authentication and i am not sure what you mean when you say place the item in the login view.  thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to help via my iPad so drawing up the code isn't easy. The loginview control can be found in the toolbar under login. This page will shine more light on the login view control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx

Comment: Sorry David i was busy with this i did not see your post.  what is it you want me to post? sorry you have to be easy on me since i am new to this

Comment: the asp content of the navigation menu, and details on how you populate this before you strip out the admin roles for none admin users.

Comment: thanks David. I just added the aspx file for the master page if you look at in my first post at the top. If uncomment the code behind in the master page then the Admin menu will appear.  I am sure i am in the admin menu role as i have created a windows user group.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20206/discussion-between-user1858332-and-david-lloyd-brookes)

Comment: it is failing the first line of the page which is where it is trying to reference the master page.  can we set it to reference to the site map?

Answer (score 1):

.Net Web does not provide properties per Menu Item to specify visibility. So it wont be possible to set specific menu items to 'appear' visible per user.
But the caveat of this is that you can however just NOT create the menu item in the first place.

Eg:
Do not add your menu item via the Visual Studio Designer view.
Add the items that are static regardless of authentication level.

in the on Page Load Event - perform the check for authentication.
If the user is authenticated, create the Menu Items you want to appear when authenticated, via the object oriented approach - utilizing their constructors and setting any needed properties.
I do this in my Site.Master page: because I want the menu to behave this way for all pages.

But you can however do it per individual page if you need to.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            MenuItem m = new MenuItem("Upload");
            m.NavigateUrl = "~/Uploader/Upload.aspx";
            NavigationMenu.Items.Add(m);
        }
    }
```